# Why is the Network Watcher on Azure not destroyed by Terraform?

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

I have a simple Terraform configuration to create azure virtual network. When I do **plan** and then **apply**, a virtual network is created inside of a resource group as expected. But in addition to this resource group, there is one more created by the name NetworkWatcherRG, and inside of it I see a network watcher.

[image: Azure Resource Groups]

And the network watcher.

[image: Azure network watcher]

Now when I run the Terraform **destroy** command, I expect that every thing is cleaned up, all the Resource groups are destroyed. But instead, everything **except for the NetworkWatcherRG and the Network Watcher inside of it are destroyed**.

Looks like the Network Watcher along with its resource group, is NOT managed by Terraform. What am I missing?

The network watcher is not immediately obvious. Its not reveled immediately. So to see that, you need to go the [simplified view of the resource groups](https://harvestingclouds.com/post/an-easter-egg-or-hidden-feature-within-the-azure-portal-simplified-view-of-all-resources/). You need to click the Refresh button atleast 5 times(each time with a 2 second time gap) or you have to wait for long time and then click refresh.

So what is this network watcher and is it that Azure is creating it by itself and not managed by Terraform?

[image: Resource Groups Simplified View]

My Terraform configuration file is as follows.

```
# Terraform settings Block
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.0.0"
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">= 2.0"
    }
  }
}

# Provider Block
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

# create virtual network
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "myvnet" {
  name                = "vivek-1-vnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"] # This is a list, it has []. If it has { }, then its a map.
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.myrg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.myrg.name
  tags = { # This is a map. This is {}
    "name" = "vivek-1-vnet"
  }
}

# Resource-1: Azure Resource Group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "myrg" {
  name     = "vivek-vnet-rg"
  location = var.resource_group_location
}


variable "resource_group_location" {
  default     = "centralindia"
  description = "Location of the resource group."
}
```

And finally the commands I use are as follows.

```
terraform fmt

terraform init

terraform validate

terraform plan -out main.tfplan

terraform apply main.tfplan

terraform plan -destroy -out main.destroy.tfplan

terraform apply main.destroy.tfplan
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before applying `terraform code` i checked in my resource groups with name `network watcher resource group` for me , by default this resource grpup is created by Azure side.

[image]

As [Mike-Ubezzi wrote on Microsoft forums](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/27211/what-is-the-networkwatcherrg.html):

> Network Watcher resources are located in the hidden NetworkWatcherRG
> resource group which is created automatically. For example, the NSG
> Flow Logs resource is a child resource of Network Watcher and is
> enabled in the NetworkWatcherRG.
>
> The Network Watcher resource represents the backend service for
> Network Watcher and is fully managed by Azure. Customers do no need to
> manage it. Operations like move are not supported on the resource.
> However,  [the resource can be
> deleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/network-watcher-create#delete-a-network-watcher-in-the-portal).

So terraform destroy will only delete the resource created by you(mentioned in  `.tfstate` file).This is the region you won't able to delete the `NetworkWatcherRG` Resource Group.

Answer (score 3):

I read the response from @RahulKumarShaw-MT . I believe the answer and it makes complete sense that terraform won't destroy resources it didn't create (unless someone can demonstrate otherwise). That said, I was able to delete the NetworkWatcherRG group using terraform! What I did to achieve this was I made sure to add a network watcher as one of my declared resources using azurerm_network_watcher (see https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/network_watcher) in the same terraform script where I requested a virtual machine resource in another separate resource group. I think you created a vnet. My script creates a vnet too, and hence why I think Azure concludes that there is a need for a network watcher maybe? I named the first resource group, which contains my network watcher, whatever I wanted; doesn't have to be 'NetworkWatcherRG'. I watched the resource group be created and destroyed successfully with Terraform (using `terraform apply` and `terraform destroy` respectively, of course) along with my VM and vnet resources. Anyway, at the end, I refreshed the Azure Portal web page and saw no resource groups or resources in my test subscription. I'm not an Azure expert, but I suspect that if Azure already sees a network watcher present, then it won't create an additional one when terraform created my resources (e.g. - in my case a vm and a vnet), as a watcher will already be present as long as terraform creates that resource first before Azure gets a chance to.